# When does `Object.preventExtensions()` seal prototype?

Tags: javascript

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) on preventExtensions states the following:

> Object.preventExtensions() only prevents addition of own properties.
>   Properties can still be added to the object prototype. However,
>   calling Object.preventExtensions() on an object **will also prevent
>   extensions** on its `__proto__`  property.

I can't seem to figure out how to use `preventExtensions` to seal prototype. Any suggestions?

Comment: This sentence seems misleading to me. It should probably be removed. Look at the last example in the examples section, I guess that's what they mean.

Comment: @FelixKling, do you mean this `var fixed = Object.preventExtensions({});`? I tried and it allows modification to the prototype

Comment: I mean the line that follows after that. You cannot **overwrite** the prototype (apparently, didn't test).

Comment: @Maximus this seems to be an error in the mdn docs as `Object.preventExtensions({}).__proto__.foo = 3` does not throw in FF or Chrome.

Comment: @FelixKling, can you post an answer? It is indeed prevents **substituation** of a prototype, not modification -`Object.setPrototypeOf(fixed, {})` throws

Comment: @JaredSmith, see my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44783231/when-does-object-preventextensions-seal-prototype?noredirect=1#comment76551389_44783231)